# ActiveMQ Artemis OutOfMemory

Tags: activemq-artemis

With ActiveMQ Artemis 2.27.1 we are getting an OutOfMemory issue when a lot of messages are sent on a destination.

We are seeing these logs:

```
2023/04/18 07:21:41.304 AMQ222038: Starting paging on address 'topic.xxx.update.V1'; size=**104875169** bytes (3312 messages); maxSize=104857600 bytes (-1 messages); globalSize=221430815 bytes (5093 messages); globalMaxSize=2147483648 bytes (-1 messages);
2023/04/18 07:21:41.351 AMQ222038: Starting paging on address 'topic.xxx.update.V1'; size=**104910890** bytes (3313 messages); maxSize=104857600 bytes (-1 messages); globalSize=221510658 bytes (5098 messages); globalMaxSize=2147483648 bytes (-1 messages);
2023/04/18 07:21:41.395 AMQ222038: Starting paging on address 'topic.xxx.update.V1'; size=**104946645** bytes (3314 messages); maxSize=104857600 bytes (-1 messages); globalSize=221620692 bytes (5104 messages); globalMaxSize=2147483648 bytes (-1 messages);
...
2023/04/19 05:06:48.343 AMQ222038: Starting paging on address 'topic.xxx.update.V1'; size=**2762590565** bytes (96258 messages); maxSize=104857600 bytes (-1 messages); globalSize=3007737936 bytes (100975 messages); globalMaxSize=2147483648 bytes (-1 messages);
```

It seems that the paging is triggered but not working. The size used for the destination is increasing.

When analyzing the dump, we can see that the memory is mainly used by topic.xxx.update.V1 destination.

Address settings. Expiry delay is defined on "topic.#".  and virtualTopicConsumerWildcards "clustered.*.>;2;selectorAware=true" to use virtual topics.
Clients are using ActiveMQ classic library and OPENWiRE protocol to connect.
We have a mix of 2 clients using virtual topics and 2 clients connected on the topic.

Any idea what could explain this?

Comment: Can you include your `address-settings`? Also, what protocol & client implementation are you using? Have you tried this on 2.28.0 (i.e. the latest release at this point)?

Comment: I've updated the description. Not tested with 2.28.0.